# How to close disable dropdown opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <div id=ControlId>
       <select id="' +ControlId + '_text" value="Select Options" style="max-width:150px;background:White;Width:150px"> <option selected>Select Options</option></select>
  </div>
  <div id=ControlId + "_child"  style="display: none" > 
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> option 1
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> option 2
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" /> option 3
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

I have created dropdownlist for multiple selection as following, how to disable default dropdown opening

this is my actural event in JQuery :

```
$("#" + ControlId).click(function () {
       $("#" + ControlId + "_child").fadeIn("slow");
       $("#" + ControlId + "_child").toggle();
});
```

How to disable default dropdown opening?

Comment: You can't set an id like this in HTML : `<div id=ControlId + "_child">`. Is `ControlId` supposed to be a variable in JavaScript?

Comment: dymanic varaible i have added multiple time , that was not my problem how to disable default dropdown opening in Jquery ?

Comment: Din't you get any errors on your console ?
As @tb11 said - you cannot set Id like this is HTML !

Comment: Looks like you are using some jQuery plugin. Please tell exactly what plugin and post the code where you initialize it. When you do this use `@` to notify.

Comment: fiddle would be appreciated

Comment: ok simply i will ask $("#" + ControlId + "_text").attr("disabled", true); it will working for me just disabled the dropdown , but i need while click dropdown ,not need to open the dropdown ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm not sure whether you're trying to **disable the dropdown**.  If so try using the below code to disable it.</strike>

```
$("#" + ControlId + "_text").attr("disabled", true);
```

Also check your `HTML` code, it has to be cleaned up.

**EDIT1:** If you're using  jQuery 1.6+, then try using prop;

```
$("#" + ControlId + "_text").prop("disabled", true);
```

**EDIT2:** Hide to option when dropdown is clicked.

```
$("#" + ControlId).click(function () {
$("#" + ControlId + " options").hide();
});
```

**EDIT3:** You're trying to have a ***placeholder for SELECT tag***, currently it is unavailable.
 Remove your inline styles for select and add the following css to your code.

```
select {
    max-width:150px;
    background:White;        
    height: 25px;
}
/* Hidden placeholder */
 select option[disabled]:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

check out this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/kRtZE/6/) in Firefox.

Comment: @Smith you don't want to show the optionlist, when it is clicked. right?

Comment: no i'm not trying to disable dropdown , i'm trying to disable dropdown opening alone

Comment: @smith then you need to hide the options when dropdown is clicked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31849/discussion-between-smith-and-user1671639)